# Contact form 7 loads forever but sends mail correctly.Unfortunately no info at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins, contact-form-7

At my wordpress site I am using Contact Form 7 plugin. It works correnctly... it sends mails but without any information at the end. I have all time the rounding circle... It should shows me that the message is sent correctly.

What could be wrong with this message  ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Contact Form 7 has has a messages area where you can configure what message you want to show to the user in different scenarios You can add text from there. If someone already configured it, look for css code that must be hiding the options.
[image]